# Solving a inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We've got the following differential equation:

$y''(x)+y(x)=h(x).$

I'm able to solve $y''(x) + y(x)=0$

But I have no clue on how to solve the inhomogeneous equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard methods that you will find on (almost) any text od differential equations:

1. Variation of constants. It works for any $h$.
2. Indeterminate coefficients. It works only for certain types of $h$.

Comment: I know the method of variation of constants but have only used it on first order DE's. How do you use it on second order?

Comment: Once you know $y_1$ and $y_2$ two linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous equation, look for a solution of the complete equation of the form $y=C_1(x)y_1(x)+C_2(x)y_2(x)$. Look for the details on a book.

Answer (score 0):

Add a third: Laplace transforms.  Works for any $h$ in principle.